# DataGridView populate

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, openfiledialog

I try to populate a DataGridView from a multi-line/multi-information .txt file selected by the user from an openfiledialog.

Line format for the .txt file:

```
Value1,dimension(111.1),pos(101h),work1(11.1),work2(22.2),work3(33.3),work4(44.4)
```

The string above could be repeated on 1 to 40lines.

The openfiledialog is correct, I guest, but I can't figure out how to use the selected file to populate my datagrid.

The other part of the problem, is read each "cell" individually to use the data somewhere else in the app..

Answer (score 0):

- Create a class with properties to match the elements of the lines.
- Iterate through the lines, splitting each on the comma and assigning
  the values to a new instance of your class
- Add that instance to a List(Of YourClass)
- Set the DataSource of the DataGridView to that List object.

Answer (score 0):

To fill your datagridview with datas coming from your file you first need to create a class representing lines.
Regarding your case it is a simple class containing properties "dimension", "pos", "work1","work2", "work3" an "work4" (maybe "name" or "id" to store you "value1" value)

Then you need to instanciate an observable collection (a generic list should be ok) of this objects (filled with values coming from the file)

once it's done you must attached the collection instance to the datagridview's datasource.

Youcan find an example here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24413/Binding-a-generic-collection-to-a-DataGridView-via

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the file into a datatable.
or add element by element to the datagrid.

There is another more complex ways that is use custom Serializer

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx and after deserialize the object 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa420a9y(v=vs.110).aspx